# Mac OSX - minSdk(API 18) > deviceSdk(API 15)

Tags: android, macos

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.1 on my Mac (Version 10.9.2) and I'm receiving the above error when trying to run the application I'm developing on the Android phone that I have connected. The Android phone is a Samsung Galaxy S Blaze SGH-T769, Android Version 4.0.4.

I'm fairly new to Android app development, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your application's `minSdkVersion` is set to 18, which corresponds to Android 4.3. Your device is an Android 4.0.4 devices, which is API Level 15. You cannot run a `minSdkVersion` 18 app on a API Level 15 device.

If your objective is to be able to run this app on that device, edit your `minSdkVersion` (`app/build.gradle` or via File > Project Structure from the Android Studio main menu) to be 15 (or lower) instead of 18.

Comment: I tried changing the minSdkVersion from 18 to 15, as you said, but I'm still getting the same error. If I were to change the Project Structure, would that effect my code at all? (From my understanding) Wouldn't my code be affected as some code is only meant for API 18+?

Comment: @Kevin: "I'm still getting the same error" -- perhaps you edited the wrong file or something. "If I were to change the Project Structure, would that effect my code at all?" -- it would affect the associated Gradle build files (e.g., `build.gradle`, `settings.gradle`, `app/build.gradle`). "Wouldn't my code be affected as some code is only meant for API 18+?" -- once you do successfully reduce the `minSdkVersion` to 15, you might start to see errors, pointing out where you are referring to classes, methods, etc. that are not available on the older Android devices that you would like to support.

Comment: my mistake. I had to rebuild the project after changing the minSdkVersion. Thank you!

Comment: @Kevin: Hmmm... I would have expected it to have done that for you automatically. Anyway, I am glad to hear that it is working!