# minSdk(API25) > deviceSdk(API24) error using Android Studio 2.2.3 and Windows 64 PRO with OnePlus3 phone

Tags: android

I'm just getting started with learning Android.

I installed Android Studio Version 2.2.3. and I'm trying to connect it with my OnePlus3 phone.

I get the following error when clicking on the green arrow:

[image: Android Studio Error]

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You have an Android 7.0 device. You set up your project to only support Android 7.1+ devices. Hence, your device is not compatible with your app. Go into `app/build.gradle` in your project, find the `minSdkVersion`, and lower it below 25.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks a lot for your swift response! I managed to sort it out as per your advise!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac OSX - minSdk(API 18) > deviceSdk(API 15)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579762/mac-osx-minsdkapi-18-devicesdkapi-15)

Answer (score 1):

Go to app/build.gradle file and set   minSdkVersion to your device max sdk version... that's all

Answer (score 0):

The application you try to debug has minSdkVersion 25 and your phone SDK is 24,
I don't think that you need minSdkVersion 25 for your app
go to app/build.gradle file and minimize the min SDK or if it's important to let your app with this SDK use higher phone